# How to overlay a quiver plot on a geodataframe plot in python

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot, geopandas

I would like to overlay a quiver plot of wind direction on a basemap in my jupyter notebook. I have a pandas dataframe that includes columns: | Latitude | Longitude | True Wind Inferred |

I have already used geopandas to create a geodataframe and plot gps track data on an osm basemap using contextily (code below). I have also been able to bin the latitude and longitude to get average True Wind Inferred (wind direction) for a "box" on the map. 
However, I haven't found any examples on how to plot a quiver plot of the binned True Wind Inferred in the boxes. I have only plotted as a scatter plot so far but the colour map does not visualize directional data well.

Imports:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
# plot inline graphics
%pylab inline
import os.path
from shapely.geometry import Point
import geopandas as gpd
import contextily as ctx
```

Sample dataframe:

```
df[['Latitude', 'Longitude', 'True Wind Inferred', 'coords']].head()

    Latitude    Longitude   True Wind Inferred  coords
0   -31.991899  115.848825  173.835559  POINT (115.848825 -31.991899)
1   -31.992036  115.848873  182.620880  POINT (115.848873 -31.992036)
2   -31.992181  115.848895  192.140276  POINT (115.848895 -31.992181)
3   -31.992308  115.848832  206.655730  POINT (115.848832 -31.992308)
4   -31.992430  115.848784  218.656646  POINT (115.848784 -31.99243)
```

Binning the dataframe:

```py
step = 0.005
to_bin = lambda x: np.floor(x / step) * step
dfLocBin['latbin'] = df['Latitude'].map(to_bin)
dfLocBin['lonbin'] = df['Latitude'].map(to_bin)
dfLocBin = df.groupby(['latbin', 'lonbin'])[['True Wind Inferred']].mean()
dfLocBin.reset_index(inplace=True)
dfLocBin['coords'] = list(zip(dfLocBin['lonbin'], dfLocBin['latbin']))
dfLocBin['coords'] = dfLocBin['coords'].apply(Point)
dfLocBin.head()

    latbin  lonbin  True Wind Inferred  coords
0   -32.015 115.790 223.149075  POINT (115.79 -32.015)
1   -32.015 115.795 222.242870  POINT (115.795 -32.015)
2   -32.015 115.800 223.710092  POINT (115.8 -32.015)
3   -32.015 115.805 225.887096  POINT (115.805 -32.015)
4   -32.015 115.810 225.298059  POINT (115.81 -32.015)
```

And plotting:

```py
def add_basemap(ax, zoom, url='http://tile.stamen.com/terrain/tileZ/tileX/tileY.png'):
    xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax = ax.axis()
    basemap, extent = ctx.bounds2img(xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax, zoom=zoom, url=url)
    ax.imshow(basemap, extent=extent, interpolation='bilinear')
    # restore original x/y limits
    ax.axis((xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax))

geo_df = gpd.GeoDataFrame(
    dfLocBin, crs  ={'init': 'epsg:4326'},
    geometry = dfLocBin['coords']
).to_crs(epsg=3857)

ax = geo_df.plot(
    figsize= (20, 20),
    alpha  = 1,
    c=dfLocBin['True Wind Inferred']
)

add_basemap(ax, zoom=15, url=ctx.tile_providers.ST_TONER)
ax.set_axis_off()
plt.title('Binned True Wind Direction')
plt.show()
```

[scatter plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ji8Qs.png)

I would like to change the type of plot from a scatter with colours to a quiver plot with arrows representing the compass direction of the wind.

Comment: Have you looked at matplotlib quiver?https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.quiver.html

Comment: I tried to reproduce this, but installing geopandas/fiona/gdal etc in my env isn't worth the whole afternoon...

Comment: @Julia I ended up using matplotlib quiver. The hard part was plotting it on the same axes as the map. I've worked it out now and posted in the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I worked it out. The X,Y for the quiver need to come from the `geometry` of the geodataframe to plot properly on the same axis. The geodataframe columns look like:

```py
geo_df.head()

latbin  lonbin  True Wind Inferred  coords  geometry
0   -32.014 115.798 220.492453  POINT (115.798 -32.014) POINT (12890574.39487949 -3765148.48502445)
1   -32.014 115.800 225.718756  POINT (115.8 -32.014)   POINT (12890797.03386108 -3765148.48502445)
```

Working Code:

```py
# bin the coordinates and plot a vector field
step = 0.002
to_bin = lambda x: np.floor(x / step) * step
df['latbin'] = df['Latitude'].map(to_bin)
df['lonbin'] = df['Longitude'].map(to_bin)
dfLocBin = df.groupby(['latbin', 'lonbin'])[['True Wind Inferred']].mean()
dfLocBin.reset_index(inplace=True)
dfLocBin['coords'] = list(zip(dfLocBin['lonbin'], dfLocBin['latbin']))
dfLocBin['coords'] = dfLocBin['coords'].apply(Point)

# ... turn them into geodataframe, and convert our
# epsg into 3857, since web map tiles are typically
# provided as such.
geo_df = gpd.GeoDataFrame(
    dfLocBin, crs  ={'init': 'epsg:4326'},
    geometry = dfLocBin['coords']
).to_crs(epsg=3857)

# ... and make the plot
ax = geo_df.plot(
    figsize= (20, 20),
    alpha  = 1
)

geo_df['X'] = geo_df['geometry'].x
geo_df['Y'] = geo_df['geometry'].y

geo_df['U'] = np.cos(np.radians(geo_df['True Wind Inferred']))
geo_df['V'] = np.sin(np.radians(geo_df['True Wind Inferred']))

ax.quiver(geo_df['X'], 
          geo_df['Y'], 
          geo_df['U'], 
          geo_df['V'],
         color='deepskyblue')


add_basemap(ax, zoom=15, url=ctx.tile_providers.ST_TONER)

ax.set_axis_off()
plt.title('Binned True Wind Direction')
plt.show()
```

[quiver on map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u0d7r.png)